# How to check audit settings on a Windows file or folder with PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, permissions, audit, auditing

I have been trying to get the audit settings from files and folders in Windows.

I need to validate for several different folders and files on Windows that the "Everyone" group has "Failure" flag checked for certain types of access attempts. I want to be able to show this using PowerShell instead of logging into each endpoint and opening each folders' properties -> advanced -> Auditing tab and taking screenshots for evidence if that's possible.

## PowerShell Script

```
# Input file containing a list of folders
$folderListFile = ".\folder_list.txt"

# Read the folder list file into an array
$folderList = Get-Content $folderListFile
    
# Loop through each folder in the list
foreach ($folderPath in $folderList) {
  # Get the audit flags for the folder
  $auditFlags = (Get-Acl $folderPath).Audit

  # Write the audit flags to the console
  Write-Output "Folder Path: $folderPath"
  Write-Output "Audit Flags: $($auditFlags.AuditToString())"
  Write-Output ""
}
```

## Contents of ".\folder_list.txt"

```
C:\
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32
```

## Output:

```
PS P:\Scripts> .\Get-FolderAuditSettings.ps1
Folder Path: C:\
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At P:\Scripts\Get-FolderAuditSettings.ps1:14 char:32
+   Write-Output "Audit Flags: $($auditFlags.AuditToString())"
+                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Audit Flags:

Folder Path: C:\Windows
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At P:\Scripts\Get-FolderAuditSettings.ps1:14 char:32
+   Write-Output "Audit Flags: $($auditFlags.AuditToString())"
+                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Audit Flags:

Folder Path: C:\Windows\System32
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At P:\Scripts\Get-FolderAuditSettings.ps1:14 char:32
+   Write-Output "Audit Flags: $($auditFlags.AuditToString())"
+                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Comment: I imagine that you're getting that error because the `$auditFlags` is an empty string. For testing purposes, change your script, so that it's (within the loop) `Write-Host $auditFlags`. Then, run it as a user who has limited or no access to the folders in your `folder_list.txt`, watch the output, and then run the script again as a user who has all the privileges.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

1. I had to add the -Audit flag to the Get-ACL module
2. Now it returns an object of type: System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAuditRule
3. I then reference the properties listed for this object.

Reference: [dotnet-api-system.security.accesscontrol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemauditrule?view=net-7.0)

```
# Input file containing a list of folders
$folderListFile = ".\folder_list.txt"

# Read the folder list file into an array
$folderList = Get-Content $folderListFile

# Loop through each folder in the list
foreach ($folderPath in $folderList) {
  # Get the audit flags for the folder
  $auditFlags = (Get-Acl $folderPath -Audit).Audit

  # Write the audit flags to the console
  Write-Output "Folder Path: $folderPath"
  Write-Output "Audit Identity: $($auditFlags.IdentityReference)"
  Write-Output "Audit Rights: $($auditFlags.FileSystemRights)"
  Write-Output "Audit Flags: $($auditFlags.AuditFlags)"
  Write-Output ""
}
```